# Changing classes with setInterval

Tags: javascript

I've made a 5x5 grid of tiles, and I'd like to create a tile that changes its class every 2 seconds.

Essentially, this tile would be turning, facing Up, Left, Down, Right -- in that particular order.

Right now, I'm putting all elements with a particular class into a nodeList/array.
Then, I iterate through each element, replacing the current color/class with the new one.

This kind of works, but appears to skip certain tiles, giving me wonky performance.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
function rotateTile(){
    var tattleTowerUpArray = document.getElementsByClassName("tattleTowerUp");
    var tattleTowerLeftArray = document.getElementsByClassName("tattleTowerLeft");
    var tattleTowerDownArray = document.getElementsByClassName("tattleTowerDown");
    var tattleTowerRightArray = document.getElementsByClassName("tattleTowerRight");

    for(var i=0; i < tattleTowerUpArray.length; i++){
        document.getElementById(tattleTowerUpArray.item(i).id).style.borderTopColor = "black";
        document.getElementById(tattleTowerUpArray.item(i).id).style.borderLeftColor = "red";
        document.getElementById(tattleTowerUpArray.item(i).id).classList.remove("tattleTowerUp");
        document.getElementById(tattleTowerUpArray.item(i).id).classList.add("tattleTowerLeft");
        }

    for(var j=0; j < tattleTowerLeftArray.length; j++){

        document.getElementById(tattleTowerLeftArray.item(j).id).style.borderLeftColor = "black";
        document.getElementById(tattleTowerLeftArray.item(j).id).style.borderBottomColor = "red";
        document.getElementById(tattleTowerLeftArray.item(j).id).classList.remove("tattleTowerLeft");
        document.getElementById(tattleTowerLeftArray.item(j).id).classList.add("tattleTowerDown");

        }

    for(var k=0; k < tattleTowerDownArray.length; k++){

        document.getElementById(tattleTowerDownArray.item(k).id).style.borderBottomColor = "black";
        document.getElementById(tattleTowerDownArray.item(k).id).style.borderRightColor = "red";
        document.getElementById(tattleTowerDownArray.item(k).id).classList.remove("tattleTowerDown");
        document.getElementById(tattleTowerDownArray.item(k).id).classList.add("tattleTowerRight");
        }

    for(var l=0; l < tattleTowerRightArray.length; l++){

        document.getElementById(tattleTowerRightArray.item(l).id).style.borderRightColor = "black";
        document.getElementById(tattleTowerRightArray.item(l).id).style.borderTopColor = "red";
        document.getElementById(tattleTowerRightArray.item(l).id).classList.remove("tattleTowerRight");
        document.getElementById(tattleTowerRightArray.item(l).id).classList.add("tattleTowerUp");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: I figured based on the title this would be a simple question to answer. Then I saw all those loops and tons of repeated code (um [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) much?) and my head exploded. I'd do it this way: https://gist.github.com/sukima/85722db0cba0826a9316

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed your code and tried to comment it. You need to add class 'tattleTower' to EVERY tile element for this to work.

Just a couple of points:

1) getElementsByClassName returns a live NodeList. That means it looks for elements every time you access it(like when you access it's length property);
2) You can avoid using 4 loops and use just 1 loop with if statements, if you add a common class to ALL elements. Like in this example you could add a class 'tattleTower'. So each element would have 2 classes. eg: class='tattleTower tattleTowerLeft'.
3) I don't quite understand why you decided to change border styles with js. You could do it in CSS in those classes. You can explicitly define what properties you want transitions to work on if you're worried about it.
4) You don't need to use id to access a particular element within a loop. You can use el[i]. Eg. el[0] will give you the first element of the array.
5) Try to cache as much as possible by using variables if you perform expensive operations.

```
function rotateTile(){

    // set up all variables at the top of the function
    // use querySelectorAll for static NodeList, instead of live nodeList
    var tattleTowerArray = document.querySelectorAll(".tattleTower"), 
        el, i, len, elClassList, elStyle;

    // use one loop instead of four
    // cache array's length for performance (to avoid asking for it on each iteration)
    for (i = 0, len = tattleTowerArray.length; i < len; i++){

        el = tattleTowerArray[i]; // cache element for performance
        elClassList = el.classList; // cache element's classList
        elStyle = el.style; // cache element's style object


        // use 'if-else if' statements to check for class (you can change it to switch block, but i don't think it'd be best here)
        if (elClassList.contains('tattleTowerUp')) {

            elStyle.borderTopColor = "black";
            elStyle.borderLeftColor = "red";

            elClassList.remove("tattleTowerUp");
            elClassList.add("tattleTowerLeft");

        } else if (elClassList.contains('tattleTowerLeft')) {

            elStyle.borderLeftColor = "black";
            elStyle.borderBottomColor = "red";

            elClassList.remove("tattleTowerLeft");
            elClassList.add("tattleTowerDown");

        } else if (elClassList.contains('tattleTowerDown')) {

            elStyle.borderBottomColor = "black";
            elStyle.borderRightColor = "red";

            elClassList.remove("tattleTowerDown");
            elClassList.add("tattleTowerRight");

        } else if (elClassList.contains('tattleTowerRight')) {

            elStyle.borderRightColor = "black";
            elStyle.borderTopColor = "red";

            elClassList.remove("tattleTowerRight");
            elClassList.add("tattleTowerUp");

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I need a bit more reputation to upvote you, etc.  Thanks for your advice.  You've delivered a cleaned up version of what I'm doing.  The direct border color changes were an alternative solution to the problem, but it was just as intermittent as the class change I had implemented.

Comment: Actually, once I added ".length" into the for loop, this got the tiles spinning perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, man. Sorry, my bad, totally forgot to type it out. Edited the answer. Glad it works for you!

Comment: This took me forever to figure out because NodeLists and HTMLCollections are mutable! Ahhh. Anyway here is the same example using CSS and DRY functional code: http://jsbin.com/lopoxawufa/1/edit?js,output